# Joining 3 tables efficiently in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables like this:

images (~10,000 rows)

```
id | place_id | filename 
---|----------|----------
 1 |     4    |  abc.jpg
 2 |     3    |  def.jpg
 3 |     4    |  ghi.jpg
 4 |     7    |  jkl.jpg
```

tags (~100 rows)

```
id |   name   |
---|----------|
 1 |   tagA   |
 2 |   tagB   |
 3 |   tagC   |
 4 |   tagD   |
```

tagsToImages (~30,000 rows)

```
id |  tag_id  | image_id
---|----------|----------
 1 |     1    |    4
 2 |     3    |    2
 3 |     2    |    4
 4 |     1    |    1
```

As an example, the last table shows that the tag with id = 1 is linked with the image with id = 4.

I've got two questions, one pretty simple (I think!), and one more difficult.

**Simple question**

Given a place_id, how can I list all the tags that have image in that place_id? An example would be:

Given place_id = 7, return tagA, tagB.

**Hard question**

What I'd like to do is to select all the images with a certain place_id, and associate each image with a list of tags like so:

Select all with place_id = 4, whilst joining to tags info.

```
 filename |    tags    
-----------------------
  abc.jpg | tagA       
  ghi.jpg | tagA, tagB
```

Would this be better to do in PHP by performing multiple queries, or can I do this using MYSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `SELECT i.place_id, t.name as tag_name

   FROM images i

   INNER JOIN tagsToImages tti ON (tti.image_id = i.id)

   INNER JOIN  tags t ON (t.id = tti.tag_id)

   WHERE i.place_id = 7`
2. `SELECT i.filename, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ',') AS tags

   FROM images i

   INNER JOIN tagsToImages tti ON (tti.image_id = i.id)

   INNER JOIN  tags t ON (t.id = tti.tag_id)

   WHERE i.place_id = 4
   GROUP BY i.filename`

It's always better to avoid multiple queries if possible.
*Be aware that the maximum length of `GROUP_CONCAT` is controlled by `group_concat_max_len` variable. If you are expecting to get a long list of concatenated strings, you might need to change the default value.

**UPDATE**
If you want the queries to display images with no tags associated, change `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s

Comment: Thanks so much! Are you some kind of wizard – this is amazing. My best attempt took so long to run that I gave up – this runs in around 300-400ms...

Comment: I just came back to ask how to show images with no tags, and you've already answered! Thanks so much!

Comment: I have one more question – if I want to join place with the name of the place from another table, why won't this query work?   SELECT i.id, i.filename, i.rating, i.caption, i.height, i.width, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags FROM gallery i, gallery_places p LEFT JOIN gallery_tagsToimages tti ON (tti.image_id = i.id) LEFT JOIN gallery_tags t ON (t.id = tti.tag_id) WHERE i.place = 101 AND i.place = p.id GROUP BY i.filename ORDER BY i.rating DESC, i.modified DESC LIMIT 16 (I've renamed some tables)

Comment: I think your query works, but not in the way you want it. You are grouping by `i.filename` , so mysql just picks any `i.id, i.rating, i..., p.name` with the specified `i.filename`. Also, I'd rather use `JOIN` than `WHERE` for joining tables

Answer (score 1):

Simple Question

```
SELECT name 
FROM images 
RIGHT JOIN tagsToImages on images.id = tagsToImages.image_id 
RIGHT JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = tagsToImages.image_id 
WHERE place_id = '7'
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple question, use `join` which will be more efficient:

```
select
    t.name as `Tag`
from
    images i
left join
    tagsToImages ti on ti.image_id = i.id
left join
    tags t on t.id = ti.tag_id
where
    place_id = $place_id
```

For hard question, see `GROUP_CONCAT`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

issuing a single query with join is better than adding loops, multiple datastructures and manually comparing the values in PHP.